# NHibernate Many-to-one cascading delete (how to?)

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have this scenario:

```
public class Survey : EntityBase
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Response : EntityBase
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Survey Survey { get; set; }
}

public class SurveyMap : ClassMap<Survey>
{
    public SurveyMap()
    {
        this.Id(e => e.Id);
        this.Map(e => e.Name);
    }
}

public class ResponseMap : ClassMap<Response>
{
    public ResponseMap()
    {
        this.Id(e => e.Id);
        this.Map(e => e.Name);
        this.References(e => e.Survey);         
    }
}
```

I want responses to be deleted automatically when I delete surveys, how to I configure this using Fluent NHibernate.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should add a property to your Survey entity :

```
public class Survey : EntityBase 
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; } 
    public IList<Response> Responses { get; set; }
}
```

And map it using cascade :

```
public class SurveyMap : ClassMap<Survey>
{
    public SurveyMap()
    {
        this.Id(e => e.Id);
        this.Map(e => e.Name);
        this.HasMany( e => e.Responses ).Inverse().Cascade().All();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd add: use on-delete="cascade" on the key (I have no idea how to set it with Fluent). That will make for much faster deletes, as the DB will take care of them.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the reference to use the `delete-orphan` option.

[**NHibernate Cascades: the different between all, all-delete-orphans and save-update**](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/12/02/nhibernatecascadesthedifferentbetweenallalldeleteorphansandsaveupdate.aspx)